# R multiple plots with common y-axis scaling and shared x-axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is my first question here. Please be nice to a (R-) newbie :)

I'm trying to arrange multiple plots from different data frames, so that they share a common y-axis and the x-axis label/numbers are only displayed under the bottom plot.

My data frames consist of the following columns:
measurement time (*messzeitpunkt_s*), mean (*z_mean*), upper limit of the confidence interval (*z_ci_up*), lower limit of the confidence interval (*z_ci_low*).

This is what I've tried:

1. I created the plots I want to stack over another:

`

```
p_neutral <- ggplot(neutral_all_mean_ci, aes(messzeitpunkt_s, z_mean, colour = " Mittelwert ")) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(messzeitpunkt_s, ymax = z_ci_up, ymin = z_ci_low), fill = "#FCE5D7", alpha=0.8) +
  labs(x = "Messzeit [s]",y = "Neutral")+
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = z_ci_low, colour =" 95% CI ")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = z_ci_up, colour = " 95% CI ")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#F7B383", "#3074B3", "#F7B383"))
```

`

I've used the same code to create the plots *p_anger, p_disgust, p_fear, p_happiness, p_sadness, p_surprise*, only by replacing the data frame *neutral_all_mean_ci* in the ggplot-function with *anger_all_mean_ci* and so on and changing the respective labels.

2. When I stack them over another using *ggarrage()*:

`ggarrange(p_neutral, p_anger, p_disgust, p_fear, p_happiness, p_sadness, p_surprise, ncol=1)`

I end up with this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecRPr.jpg).

Now I would like to have a common y-axis scale (so the plots show the same range) and the x-axis label/numbers only at the bottom plot.

Can someone please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I think you can use the `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 1.5))` in all plots and `labs(x="Messzeit [s]")` only in the last `geom_line()`, like this:

```r
p_neutral <- ggplot(neutral_all_mean_ci, aes(messzeitpunkt_s, z_mean, colour = " Mittelwert ")) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(messzeitpunkt_s, ymax = z_ci_up, ymin = z_ci_low), fill = "#FCE5D7", alpha=0.8) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 1.5)) +
  labs(x = "",y = "Neutral")+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 1.5)) +
  geom_line() + labs(x="") +
  geom_line(aes(y = z_ci_low, colour =" 95% CI ")) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 1.5)) + labs(x="") +
  geom_line(aes(y = z_ci_up, colour = " 95% CI ")) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 1.5)) + labs(x="Messzeit [s]") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#F7B383", "#3074B3", "#F7B383"))
```

Let me know if this could help you because I couldn't run it without your dataset.

Comment: Hey John, many thanks for your answer! Adding the x-label to the last subplot only worked well! 
Adding the scale limits by hand worked also, but I was searching for something like "scales = free", as you can use in the facet functions, so it automatically fits the scale to the data to be plotted

Comment: @blobfish987 and the facet functions are not an option for you in this case?